# Como fazer com que uma div não sobreponha outra div?

Tags: html, css, div

Tenho um div que é meu menu vertical, ao lado dele quero colocar uma div que preencha todo o espaço restante que será onde vai carregar meu conteúdo, mas o que acontece é que uma div está sobrepondo a outra quando diminuo o navegador de tamanho:

Postei um JSFiddle com o css pro post não ficar tão extenso

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col col-sm-2">

      <ul class="side-menu">

      <div class="side-menu-user-infos">
          <div class="side-menu-user-photo">
              <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="(user$ | async) as username; else login">
              <div class="side-menu-user-name">
                  {{ username.username }}
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="side-menu-user-options">
              <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-power-off" (click)="logout()"></i>           
          </div>

      </div>

      <li>
          <a>
              <span class="fas fa-chalkboard"></span>
              Menu
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a>
              <span class="fas fa-user-plus"></span>
              Menu
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a>
              <span class="fas fa-cart-plus"></span>
              Menu
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a>
              <span class="fas fa-store"></span>
              Menu
          </a>
      </li>    
      <li>
          <a>
              <span class="fas fa-file-alt"></span>
              Menu
          </a>
      </li>    
      <li>
          <a>
              <span class="fas fa-chart-bar"></span>
              Menu
          </a>
      </li>    
      <li>
          <a>
              <span class="fas fa-cog"></span>
              Menu
          </a>
      </li>   
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>



<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Meu JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cxbdpw8r/1/

Comment: faz assim na `content` coloca um `width` até achar que esta bom, sobre ela sobrepor o menu deixa responsivo, entra nesse site https://mydevice.io pega o tamanho da sua tela e divide `content / tamanho da tela` e assim pra todas as divs, lembrando que apaga o valor dps da virgula conta duas casas e no final do resultado coloca o sinal de `%`, pesquise sobre `media queries` e `viewport`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara vou ser sincero, o seu código estava meio bagunçado então preferi nem usa-lo para te responder, até pq o Bootstrap já sugere uma opção para fazer um Dashboard desse tipo como vc pode ver aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Quando vc opta por usar um *framework* tipo o *Bootstrap* vc tem que ter em mente que deve seguir algumas regras do sistema!** E talvez a principal regra seja o sistema de Grid...

Eu fiz esse modelo tentando customizar o mínimo possível o CSS, a acredito que cheiguei em um resultado que pode te ajudar muito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código da imagem acima.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <style>
    .menu {
      position: fixed;
    }
    .conteudo {
      height: 200vh;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
      .col-2 {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid pt-5">
    <div class="row mt-1">
      <div class="col-2 col-sm-3 menu">
        menu
      </div>
      <div class="col-10 col-sm-9 ml-auto conteudo bg-danger">
        conteúdo
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sensacional, Hugo, era exatamente onde queria chegar, meu código ta bem confuso? Será que consigo chegar em um resultado anterior utilizando meu css + o seu exemplo?

Comment: Uma outra dúvida, vale a pena utilizar o bootstrap no desenvolvimento de uma aplicação ou ele me limita em algumas regras como você havia dito na resposta e ai devo optar por utilizar somente o css?

Comment: @FernandoMunhoz sim da para vc continuar usando parte do seu CSS no Bootstrap, mas minha dica sempre é que tente usar o máximo do Bootstrap para precisar fazer o mínimo de CSS extra... Isso via te poupar tempo e evitar bug como o que vc estava tendo. Na Col-2 vc pode tentar colocar sua lista e ver como ela se comporta, o mais provável é que vc vai precisa retirar alguns CSSs e não fazer outros... E o Bootstrap é sim uma boa ferramenta, mas tem que saber usar, de uma lida na documentação vai te ajudar muito https://getbootstrap.com/docs